# Making the "hook" "pull to refresh" code work

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, refresh

I have put in the code that is supposed to refresh the website after it's pulled but it is not working. I got the code here: http://usehook.com/
This is the site I'm trying to get it to work on: http://hushmagazine.ca/

In my  I have:

```
<link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/hook/hook.css?v=1" rel="stylesheet">
```

And in the  at the top, I put:

```
<div class="hook" id="hook"><div class="hook-loader"><div class="hook-spinner"></div></div></div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/hook/mousewheel.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/hook/hook.min.js"></script>
```

Thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the code? The different calls you are making as well as your html?

Comment: just added the code, most of it I took from the examples on the website.

Comment: Are you calling `$('#yourID').hook();`?

Comment: I hadn't. I just added 
    <script $('#hook').hook();> </script>
in the body. Jquery not my strength, so I just pasted this from the example on the site.

Comment: I added an answer based on your input. Let me know if that works out for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#hook').hook(); //Where hook is the id of the parent div
    });
</script>
```

in the head that is between the following tags: `<head></head>`

Comment: Thanks that worked! At least in my web browser. But for some reason not working on the iPhone

Comment: The plugin is unfortunately not mobile compatible! Sorry!

Comment: ah really, that's the reason I am actually wanting to implement this whole thing :) So that it can be refreshed on a mobile.

Comment: Ha that's too bad, sorry about that! If my answer helped you with your question, would you mind accepting it? [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Comment: Done, I was wondering what I can do in this regard, because I still don't have enough privilege to rate answers. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually, what am I saying, their website works on my mobile. It actually should be working on the mobile as well.

Comment: I'm reviewing enqueueing jquery, as this is a WP based website. Maybe that's one issue..

Comment: That indeed could be, but if you go on the hook website, it doesn't work on the phone, so I don't think it will work on mobile with any website. You should look into different plugins, they are a bunch of them out there that offer the same feature.

Comment: I just tired again and their site actually does work on my iPhone. Actually, I'd even bought a plugin for this for $10 online which is also not working, the author is not responding and I just didn't want to ask about it on this forum as it's about code that was paid for.. The code is uploaded on the site.